# exact url querystring param value replace with regex

Tags: regex

My URL is like :

https://www.example.com?vid=123124321524

I will have to replace vid value with "--notavailable--"
So it should be:

https://www.example.com?vid=--notavailable--

I will have to use JS `.replace()` function(I have to use Regex).

There might be multiple params, should be exact param(XXXvid should NOT match)

Basically i have to pass solution to array like:  `["regex","new param value"]`

For example

```
  "https://www.example.com?vid=123124321524".replace(/[?|&]vid=\K([^&#]*)/,"--notavailable--")
```

Why is not working? 
EDIT: I realised it work with php not JS

I have tried lots of thing, still no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess javascript doesn't know `\K`, you could use:

```js
var input = "https://www.example.com?vid=123124321524"
var output = input.replace(/([?&]vid=)[^&#]+/,"$1--notavailable--");
console.log(output);
```